# Rotation Matrix Notation

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, linear-transformations

Please excuse the very basic question.

Say I have a rotation matrix $Q$ that takes a frame $A$ to a frame $A$---an active rotation.

What is the standard notation (using left/right subscripts/superscripts) to denote this transform (so that it's clear which frame the transform acts on and which frame the transform produces)?

Comment: I think in some cases where there are two coordinate systems, someone *might* incorporate the names of the coordinate systems as subscripts in the name of a transformation, e.g. $T_{AB}.$ But that's not a standard notation, it's just a choice of how to write a name to more easily remember what it is for. For a rotation that maps points to other points in the same coordinate system I wouldn't expect to see the coordinate system's name incorporated in the name of the transformation in any way.

Comment: Trouble is there are several widely used conventions for rotation transformations. A rotation can be active (rotate a vector A into vector A' relative to a fixed frame X) or it can be passive (rotate frame X itself into frame X' so the matrix expresses vector A in X'). And it's agh, frustrating, that no one ever says which convention they're using, even though the math, if you spend 5 minutes examining it, reveals they're using one or the other. I figured this was just sloppiness and that there must be standard notation to clearly communicate which convention the author is using. There isn't?